# How to retrieve logged in user's contact-->Account-->Parent-->custom field in validation rule. Is it possible?

Tags: validation-rule, user

I am using below formula to retrieve logged in user's contact's Account's Parent's field in validation rule. It is throwing error that Agency Queue does not exist.

Is it possible to derive this? Please help. It is a validation rule.

Error: It is not detecting logged in user's contact's Account's details.

AND(
ISCHANGED( OwnerId ) ,  BEGINS(OwnerId, "00G"),
$Profile.Name == 'Partner Community for GA Admin',

Owner:Queue.Name <> $User.Contact.Account.Parent.Agency_Queue__c
)

Comment: Please edit your question with more details. Your question is confusing here. Not sure you want to create a formula field or validation rule? It will be easy to help you if you can provide more details.

Comment: Is `Agency_Queue__c` a field on Account?  Also, you can do `$User.Account.Parent.Agency_Queue__c`

Comment: Usually the user would only have a contact unless they are and experience cloud user - is this the case?

Comment: @Caspar Harmer--Yes, it is partner user